# Why can we simulate any measurement involving $U=R+iQ$ using $U'=R\otimes I+Q\otimes R_x(2\pi)$ instead?

Tags: quantum-gate, measurement

In a book named ["INTRODUCTION TO QUANTUM ALGORITHMS VIA LINEAR ALGEBRA"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262045254/introduction-to-quantum-algorithms-via-linear-algebra/), the authors say:

For any complex $N×N$ matrix $U$, we can uniquely write $$U = R + iQ$$
Assume we have $$ U' = R \otimes I + Q \otimes R_x(2\pi) $$

$R_x(2\pi)$ is of the form $$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix} $$

My question is, why can we simulate any measurements involving $U$ by measurements involving $U'$ instead? Simulate any measurements means that if we measure outcome $|x⟩$
in sate $U|ψ⟩$
, it equivalen when we measure outcome $|x⟩$
in state $U′|ψ⟩|0⟩$

Comment: Can you more clearly explain your question? What do you exactly mean by measurement involving $U$ and also simulating it by measurement involving $U'$? Also, please link relevant text/material/resources if any.

Comment: @FDGod i'm reading a book called "INTRODUCTION TO QUANTUM ALGORITHMS VIA
LINEAR ALGEBRA" - Richard J. Lipton and Kenneth W. Regan. It's a problems without answer in the book (problem number 7.8, page 115). Actally i'm not so sure about what simulate any measurements mean. Maybe any circuits involve $U$, we can somehow use $U'$ instead, and the result after measuring is the same somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to that book. Is $U$ a unitary or a hermitian matrix? A unitary matrix does not correspond to a measurement afaik. Or do you mean first apply $U$ to your state and then perform a $Z$-measurement? even if that's the case, $U'$ seem to have a higher dimension than $U$. I am sorry, your question does not make any sense to me.

Comment: please edit the question to include any additional contextualising information, such as the book you're taking this from. Also, I'm guessing there should be additional assumptions on $R$ and $Q$ here, such as whether you assume them to be real, or whether you assume them to be Hermitian. Is $U$ Hermitian? More generally, you should clarify what "measurement involving $U$" means here

Comment: @glS Not Hermitian, just unitary.

Comment: @FDGod i think it means that if we measure outcome $|x⟩$ in sate $U|ψ⟩$, it equivalen when we measure outcome $|x⟩$ in state $U'|ψ⟩|0⟩$

Answer (score 0):

In my version of the book $\tilde{U}$ is defined as
\begin{align}
\tilde{U} = R \otimes I + Q \otimes R_x(\pi),
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
R_x(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \\ -\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
i.e.,
\begin{align}
R_x(\pi) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
In this case,
\begin{align}
\tilde{U} = \begin{pmatrix} R & Q \\ -Q & R \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Now, we have
\begin{align}
\tilde{U} |\psi \rangle |\psi \rangle = \begin{pmatrix}(R + Q)|\psi \rangle \\ (R- Q)|\psi \rangle \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

By measuring this state, we can reconstruct the corresponding measurement result for $(R+iQ)|\psi \rangle$.